# disable fish shell showing env variable value on tab

Tags: shell, fish

Can I disable fish shell showing the values being shown on the screen when I type echo e.g $FOO .

Current I see when I do `$F <tab>` I see my shell shows all the environment variables with `F` and then on the right said of my prompt it displays their values like `(Variable: <value of the environment value)`

Comment: It's in the C++ source code: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/f184061c163d0fb72a5555d4a78df78807906e0a/src/complete.cpp#L62 and https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/f184061c163d0fb72a5555d4a78df78807906e0a/src/complete.cpp#L1211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "No". This is not configurable in fish.